# spring-integration: mock requestFactory on HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Tags: mockito, spring-integration, mockmvc

Since upgrading spring-integration to 5.3.10.RELEASE we can't mock the requestFactory on HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler anymore in the unit tests, it is actually checked if the requestFactory setter has been called and an exception is thrown in that case.
So, how to configure the HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.requestFactory now with a Mockito instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check there is like this:

```
public void setRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {
    assertLocalRestTemplate("requestFactory");
    this.restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
}
```

That means that you have been providing a `RestTemplate` into this `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`. The `requestFactory` is essentially a property of the `RestTemplate`. So, consider to set your mock into that external `RestTemplate` instead.

Comment: ok, did that, next Problem: when(factory.createRequest(new URI(url), requestMethod)).thenReturn(request) does not match anymore, seems like the uri is changed somewhere down the flow

Comment: Well, might not be relevant, but I'd suggest to learn MockMvc framework. There is exactly `MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory`. Otherwise, just debug it to see how it is changed and from where. See `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange()`  as an entry point from where it calls the `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Well, it seems there was some change with the encoding, but setting EncodingMode.NONE in DefaultUriBuilderFactory seems to resolve that. Now I'm only left with the problem that some tests fail when run in the suite, but pass on their own.

Comment: That seems to be caused by the mocks not running properly anymore in the outbound gateways, meaning that the response stream is still at the final position, if the same outcome is used in the following test:
body = {ByteArrayInputStream@19183} 
 buf = {byte[147876]@19207} [60, 63...776 more]
 pos = 147876
 mark = 0
 count = 147876
in .m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.2.20.RELEASE/spring-web-5.2.20.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/client/MessageBodyClientHttpResponseWrapper.java:90
Any idea, why that happens? I explicity reset the stream before setting it

Comment: I think this deserves its own SO thread with much more details